# Service Based Database .MDF

Tags: c#, database, windows, winforms

I am in a need for storing data generated by C# window form app. I used service based database and i created tables i needed then i used linq for inserting values in these tables. I actually saved my data by using it, after debugging i found all the data are erased. I could not find my values i gave during runtime. Can any one help me solving it? i need a local database for saving my data, i am creating win form app which doesn't use SQL SERVER in my client system.

Comment: Are you overwriting your database file every time you run your application?

Answer (score 2):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar to this and may be it's the same. A copy of your database is saved in `\bin\Debug\` when you use `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdf`. In debug mode, your data are being saved to this copy.

That could be solved if you provide the full path to the database file e.g. C:\xxxx\yyy\mydatabase.mdf which is not portable. Hope this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the App.Config file change the path to your local DB path

   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=**C:\Users\Gerry\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseLocalApplication\DatabaseLocalApplication**\Customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

This will direct the save operation to the correct database.  You can get this string by clicking on your database and copying the entry in the **Full Path property**

THEN  Set the Copy To Output Directory of your database to **Do Not Copy**